# To find distinct document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let consider a collection like this:

```
   {"to": 'jhony', "satus": 'no'   }
   {"to": 'jhony', "satus": 'yes'   }
   {"to": 'king', "satus": 'yes'   }
   {"to": 'jhony', "satus": 'yes'   }
```

Know I want to retrieve with condition where to = 'jhony' and status = 'yes' without any duplicate(repetition).

I.e output should be

```
            {"to": 'jhony', "satus": 'yes'   }
```

How can I achieve it using mongoose in node js.

I tried like this

```
     Chat.find().distinct({ to: { $in: [ now ] }, status: { $in: [ sot ] } }, function(err, docs){
```

then I got error as:

```
          No value for 'distinct' has been declared.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want to use `findOne`:

```
Chat.findOne({ to: 'jhony', satus: 'yes' }, function(err, result) {
  ...
});
```